# How to handle Node.js API errors with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am currently developing a RESTful API with the help of Node.js and a client with React.

I am at the very beginning, ie the creation of a user via a registration form, and I realized that I do not really know how to handle the errors that my API sends me with React.

For example if I want to register with a username that is already taken, the controller of my API will throw an error :

```
throw {status: 422, message: "Username already used"}
```

My React client will retrieve it and display it in the console at the moment, but it displays a very general error (Request failed with status code 422) and not the message "Username already used"

```
_addUser(username, email, password)
 .then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
 })
 .catch((err) => {console.log(err.message)})
```

Does anyone have an idea of ​​how to solve my problem? Or another way to handle errors?

Comment: Errors like the one you are describing are valid responses.  You should check the status code and then change React state so that you can render a nice message for your user.

Comment: @DavinTryon how can I check the status code in my React app ?

Comment: it depends what http library you are using. looks like it should be at `res.status`.

Comment: i'm using express, if i console.log res.status in the .catch the value is undefined

Answer (score 5):

Your Backend Node.js code:

```
return res.status(500).json({message: "Email already registered"})
```

Your Frontend React or React Native code:

```
try{// some code}
catch (error){
   console.log(error.response.data.message)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.response); // err.response.status will give you the error code.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but I figured out why your custom error isn't showing. In your catch block, instead of console logging:

```
err.message
```

Try logging:

```
err.**response**
```

Look at this in your console and display accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

You should throw error with the `new` keyword. Then you should be able to display the message.

```
throw new Error('Username already used')
```

Or if you are using express, you can go like this:

```
res.status(422).send('Username already used')
```

Comment: I'm getting "Error: Request failed with status code 500" using this, still not my custom error message :/

Comment: I'm using Express but your second suggestion is still not giving me my custom message

Comment: Then you can check for the status code, 422 in your case, and display error message in your React application based on this code.

Comment: But how can i get the status code in my React app ?

Comment: @Paul28000 what does you `console.log(err)` display?

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/user 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)

Answer (score -1):

```
Please refer a below link:
https://medium.com/@chiragpatel.cmpicamsit15/error-handling-from-express-js-node-js-to-react-axios-error-handling-7758de90d365

**Server Side Node Js Code :**

   module.exports = (app) => {
app.put(‘/updateUser’, (req, res, next) => {
passport.authenticate(‘jwt’, { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
}
if (info !== undefined) {
console.error(info.message);
res.status(403).send(info.message);
} else {
User.findOne({
where: {
username: req.body.username,
},
}).then((userInfo) => {
if (userInfo != null) {
console.log(‘user found in db’);
userInfo
.update({
first_name: req.body.first_name,
last_name: req.body.last_name,
email: req.body.email,
})
.then(() => {
console.log(‘user updated’);
res.status(200).send({ auth: true, message: ‘user updated’ });
});
} else {
console.error(‘no user exists in db to update’);
res.status(401).send(‘no user exists in db to update’);
}
});
}
})(req, res, next);
});
};


**Client-Side (React JS) :**


updateUser = async (e) => {
const accessString = localStorage.getItem(‘JWT’);
if (accessString === null) {
this.setState({
loadingUser: false,
error: true,
});
}
const {
first_name, last_name, email, username
} = this.state;
e.preventDefault();
try {
const response = await axios.put(
‘http://localhost:3003/updateUser’,
{
first_name,
last_name,
email,
username,
},
{
headers: { Authorization: `JWT ${accessString}` },
},
);
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
console.log(response.data);
this.setState({
updated: true,
error: false,
});
} catch (error) {
console.log(error.response.data);
this.setState({
loadingUser: false,
error: true,
});
}
};
```